# How do I fix "The active test run was aborted" in Visual Studio's Test Explorer?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, visual-studio-2017

"Run All" from "Test Explorer" does not complete (VS2017 Enterprise) anymore.  It stalls with Passed (411), Not Run (309).  The counts vary a little, usually roughly half and half.

The output window (Visual Studio | Output tab | Show output from:  Tests) contains the following error message:

"The active test run was aborted. Reason: Unhandled Exception: System.AppDomainUnloadedException: Attempted to access an unloaded AppDomain."

The tests continue to run fine in ReSharper (720 of 720 pass).  R# is where I usually run my tests.  I jump over to Microsoft's "Test Explorer" when I am trying to Analyze Code Coverage (though the tests stall with or without code coverage).  It (Analyze Code Coverage) worked as recently as 5/15/2018 (and at least a half dozen to a dozen times before that).
[image]

Comment: The same exact source code behaved differently on 2 machines in at least 1 parallel test.  A Windows 10 Surface tablet ran 771/771 tests without trouble using "Analyze Code Coverage".  At the exact same time, a Windows 7 desktop PC failed to run 319 of 771 tests (status "Not Run Tests (319)").  ReSharper test runner always works fine on both machines.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Microsoft test runner was being tripped up by a single unit test class that happened to have Task.Run() calls such as the following:

```
    var task = Task.Run(async () =>
    {
        <various code>
    });
```

These tests were **missing calls to task.Wait()** to wait for each task to finish before exiting the test.

(This appears to trip up the Microsoft test runner but not the ReSharper test runner.  Specifically, the Microsoft Test Runner aborts the sln test run and skips 300+ tests.  ReSharper was able to run all tests without incident.)

Aside:  The reason for the varied behavior on Windows 7 versus Windows 10 is because the test class was for a Windows 10 sensitive 3rd party control/library.

Answer (score 11):

Check the tests output pane for more details - open the output window and select "Tests" option from the "Show output from" combo box.

In my case, my tests project was targeting a version of .NET core I didn't have installed. I just had to change the project target framework to the correct version and it solved the problem.

Comment: Not surprisingly, this can also occur in VS 2019, if there's a problem with a test/code being tested.  In my case, there was a stack overflow in my code (can happen when working with only 5 hours sleep), so the tests were being aborted.

Answer (score 2):

Just a simple

**Build** **->** **Clean Solution**

helped me.

Comment: You probably meant Build -> **Clean** Solution

Comment: Think that localization depend on VS version, so yes Clear/Clean the same

Answer (score 0):

Check Output window after setting output window drop down to tests.

My issue was that one of the test was doing an infinite loop.

Answer (score 0):

An infinite recursion was causing this problem for me.

The stack overflow exception does not get reported as a test failure.(Probably because there's no stack frame left to report it).

Hope this helps someone get unstuck quicker.